# Android Size Analyzer Plugin Error - IDE Fatal Error ("AnalyzeMenu" isn't registered)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How to fix this Android Plugin Error without Disabling the Plugin?

Every time I open Android Studio, I'm getting IDE Fatal Error for `Android Size Analyzer Plugin (0.3.0)`

**This is the StackTrace on clicking the ballon in the bottom right.**

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup (AnalyzeAppSizeGroup): group with id "AnalyzeMenu" isn't registered; action will be added to the "Other" group [Plugin: com.android.tool.sizereduction.plugin]
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.reportActionError(ActionManagerImpl.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.reportActionError(ActionManagerImpl.java:390)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.getParentGroup(ActionManagerImpl.java:910)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processAddToGroupNode(ActionManagerImpl.java:876)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processGroupElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:820)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processActionsChildElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerPluginActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:508)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.<init>(ActionManagerImpl.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:48)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:660)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:54)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:41)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:115)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:69)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:411)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:394)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionManager.getInstance(ActionManager.java:28)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeMenuBar.lambda$doWithLazyActionManager$4(IdeMenuBar.java:277)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:201)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**This is a Screenshot of the Error.**

[image: Android Size Analyzer Plugin - Error]

**What I tried:**

- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Deleted `.gradle` and `.idea` folders
- Disabled and Enabled the Plugin
- Removed and Re-installed the Plugin
- Reinstalled a fresh copy of `Android Studio 4.1.1`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!